# validating an email address properly with PHP

Tags: php, validation, email

I am trying to write a script that does the following:
Prints the users message to the screen and emails it to them as well.

here is my code For some reason it tells me my email address is invalid when it is a valid email address, any suggestions? what am i missing? :-\

```
<?php
  if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post');

  $errors = null;
  $success = true;

  function checkEmail($email){
      return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

 if($_POST){
$errors = array();
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Your Comment';
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: blahblah69@gmail.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To:
     mitides.constantin@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();



if(!$to || !$message){
    $errors[] ="Please fill in both a email and a message.";
} else if(!checkEmail($to) && $_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'],
   FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));{
    $errors[]= print ('You did not enter a valid email, please try again.');
 }
 if($errors || !$_POST){

    if($errors){
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error. "<br />";
        }
    }
}
if(!$errors && $success){
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) && print($_POST['message']);

  } ?>
```

Comment: You can't count on 50 pairs of hands how many questions are similar to this.

Comment: `$errors[] = print('...')` is wrong.

Comment: what's your php version? could be a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: @WaleedKhan It's not so much wrong as it is confusing ;-) because the final result is the same

Comment: @Nile I wouldnt have posted it if i found those questions useful

Comment: @user1905577 Maybe you just don't know *how* to use those questions.

Comment: @WaleedKhan That will actually just make a new value in $errors of `1`.

Comment: @Nile Which is wrong, no?

Comment: @WaleedKhan Thanks, what do you mean it is wrong would you mind explaining what the right way to write it is?

Comment: @WaleedKhan You could say :)

Comment: Anyone?... It may be something simple but I'm a beginner Id really appreciate the help, Although there are similar questions to it I still dont understand it, kindness would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to just isolate the value of `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`? Does it return `false`?

Comment: Isolating it seemed to work but im curious to know why it didnt work when i had my code checking two things at once, I was trying to make it more clean/ less code to type but i guess that was a fail lol (i also fixed the errors[] = print thing ...I see why that wasnt necessary

Answer (score 0):

at first put else if part in a bracket such like this
($_POST['message'] = filter_var($_POST['message'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))